# Extract Numerical Portion From String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number of strings that have either one of the following forms

1. empty string
2. 0
3. A string containing a number (that may have a - sign before it and may have a decimal point in it) followed by a space, followed by some other characters.  For example `-234.44 ABC`

   1. In case 1. I want to extract empty string
   2. In case 2 I want to extract 0
   3. In case 3 I want to extract the numerical portion.  In the example it would be `-234.44`

What would the regular expression be for this?

Incidentally we will never have strings like

```
0000 ABC
00.3 ABC
+1.7 ABC
.9 ABC
-
```

Comment: Can you show your attempts to solve the problem? This will help us provide appropriate explanations. Also, please specify which regex implementation/host language or environment you are using.

Comment: Are these numbers always at start?

Comment: @anubhava Only in cases 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/1)

Comment: @vks I don't want to match .9 ABC

Comment: @vks: Hope it doesn't become a long commenting session but [you can see MATCH INFORMATION of your regex here](https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/2) and note what is the main difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
([+-]?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This simple regex should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/9

You can also use `^([+-]?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)` if you dont have anything else at the start of line.

Use

```
^(?=.*\d)(?:[+-](?=\d|\.\d))?\d*(?:\.\d+)?|^$
```

If you have `+-` in your inputs.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jG2wO4/11

Comment: This is incorrect. It will also match just a `+` or a `-`.